# What could be some reasons for a low accuracy score in a Logistic Regression model?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, project

I am building a ML project on Bank Default classification and getting low accuracy score of 56% and precision of 61%. I know this can be improved further. Please, let me know some factors that could result in improving the score.

The data is about loan repayment and I have to classify the customers as Defaulter or Non Defaulters.My train-test ratio is 70%:30%.

' X=loan.drop("loan_status",axis=1)
    Y=loan["loan_status"]' 
 `Xtrain,Xtest,Ytrain,Ytest=train_test_split(X,Y,test_size=0.30,random_state=6)
loan_model=LogisticRegression()
Prediction=loan_model.predict(Xtest)`
Classification Report:
 precision    recall  f1-score   support

```
       0       0.41      0.22      0.29        59
       1       0.61      0.79      0.69        91
```

micro avg       0.57      0.57      0.57       150
   macro avg       0.51      0.51      0.49       150
weighted avg       0.53      0.57      0.53       150
Confusion matrix:
[[13 46]
 [19 72]]
Accuracy Score:
Accuracy Score is:  0.5666666666666667

Comment: Provide us with a snippet of your data, nobody can just guess what your data looks like.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your data or code, we can only give you **general advice** on improving your accuracy. 
The followings are two main ones that come to my mind,

1- Low accuracy on a classification means your classes are **not very well separable with the current features** you have. Remedy for this would be finding more (and better) features.

2- If you have **enough observations**, try models with **more complex decision boundaries** such as **SVM** or NN with deep layers and neurons.